# How do I mount a newly added disk in Linux?

Tags: mount

The problem is this:

[Why can't we mount multiple filesystem in same mountpoint?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/162279/why-cant-we-mount-multiple-filesystem-in-same-mountpoint)

I want to mount them to `/` partition but I don't think it's possible thing to do as per the above question.

Our enterprise has gave us 1TB of disk space to add in the server. They've already installed the disk, we just need to mount it using some linux commands.

We're using centos 7, but things are same in almost every UNIX machines.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/125257/how-do-i-add-an-additional-hard-drive

As per this (2), I am stuck at 2.1 because I'm not aware why'd I create a mount point? I just want to mount that partition to `/`. I'm worried because I want my current partition that is storing the logs to use this. Thankfully, the server is not using LVM.

How'd I do it? Is it possible in Linux?

Comment: It would have been easier with LVM as you can add the new storage to existing mount point which isn't the case while using regular partitions.

Comment: What's "thankful" about not using LVM? that is a pretty bad idea. You get a lot of flexibility, like being able to do what you want here, for free, when using LVM. I haven't set up a non-embedded system without LVM in about a decade, and I don't regret it at all.

Comment: I find LVM hard to learn that's why. Didn't know it was such a good idea. Resources to get headstarted with LVMs? I tried to learn from Nehra classes and I could learn nothing.

Comment: Personally, I just installed a linux distro selecting the "LVM" option in the installer (all the big distro installers support that these days); not anything to learn to get a running system, and afterwards, I've just read `man lvm` and `man lvcreate`, `man pvcreate`, `man vgextend` as I needed them.

Comment: See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at `https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml`, or read `man hier`.
  
It explains where things go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- create a `/etc/profile.d/custom_aliases.sh` file; `chmod 644` it assuming its ownership is `root.root`; follow the layout of existing files there.

  - the `.sh` is for bash shell accounts, if using `csh` or `tcsh` as specified in `/etc/passwd` then make the file `custom_aliases.csh`
  - in it simply have

    `alias lsblk2='lsblk -o size,fstype,model,name,serial,uuid'`
- typing `lsblk2` will provide enough useful information for you to identify the new disk.

A new disk will show up without a partition most likely, such as `/dev/sdb` for example and not also show a `/dev/sdb1`.  Regardless..

To format a disk in linux for use do the following

- identify the correct disk via the `lsblk` command, using the options I mentioned above

  - reference `man lsblk` for more useful `-o` options
- if the disk shows up as `/dev/sdf` for example

  - `parted /dev/sdf`

    - `mklabel gpt`
    - `mkpart primary 0% 100%`
    - `quit`
  - `mkfs.xfs /dev/sdf`
  - choose a different filesystem than `xfs` if desired
  - `mkdir /whatever`
  - `mount /dev/sdf1 /whatever`

To make the disk mount automatically during every boot

- recognize the **UUID** of `/dev/sdf` per the above, changing `sdf` according to your system;  Use the UUID...
- in `/etc/fstab` do

  - `UUID=<your uuid>   /whatever   xfs   defaults,nofail  0  0`

    - change `xfs` accordingly, to what you used in the `mkfs` command
    - the `nofail` option will allow the system to boot if that disk is not there and does not mount, which may be good or bad depending on what you are doing

      - bad if you expect a 10tb disk to mount and it doesn't and your root partition *whatever* folder then fills up, with the root disk being 600gb for example.

> I just want to mount that partition to /.  How'd I do it? Is it possible in Linux?

`/` is the *root partition*, and is the local disk in the system.  You don't mount other disks to just `/`.  They have to be mounted to some directory name at least, underneath `/`;  that's just how it works not sure how else to explain it everything needs some mount point and just `/` is the highest mount point from which all others reside *under*.  So you could do `mkdir /logs` and mount your new disk to the `/logs` folder, or you could do `mkdir /var/logs` and mount likewise; but recognize the existing `/var/log` system folder, which you could make that specifically a separate disk if desired just don't mix the linux `/var/log` folder up with your log folder.  Whatever naming convention and housekeeping method is up to you.  Any folder, however many levels deep under `/` can be a mount point.